# Dynamic URL aliasing?

Tags: path-aliases, uri

Let's say we have a section `/latest-projects` with a menu block listing nodes sorted descending by their post date. Thus, the first item will often change and be the freshest one. Is it possible to make the `/latest-projects` alias always link to (= open) the top-most node?

Comment: Why not you create a block view or page view from Views UI? Probably I did not understand your question well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed it is.

Steps you will need to do:

1. Create a custom module
2. Implement [hook_menu()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7)
3. Define the route 'latest-projects', and make the menu callback a function
4. In the custom menu callback function do SQL or whatever to find the latest project (maybe use EnityFieldQuery in Drupal 7)
5. Use [drupal_goto()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_goto/7) to then redirect the user to the latest project node

Note in the above solution, a redirect is used to send the user to the project node, but if needed you can also simply render the node on the page as another idea.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. Would this pick up the translation for current language?

Comment: Because you are writing the menu callback with custom PHP, you can also add language as a clause in the query to find on projects of the correct language.